# Android how to open a file, compute something, write to the file and then close it as rapidly as possible?

Tags: android, performance, file, android-ndk, output

I am working on an android project which needs to create and write files rapidly. I am using ndk for this purpose and found that fopen() call takes uncertain amount of time, from minimum ~30ms to several seconds whening running from the main thread. After opening the file, I then need to compute some results, store results into the opened file and then close it.

I am trying to put it into another thread but not sure if it helps at all and how to handle  scheduling issue if it does. I am also thinking about possibly opening many of those file descriptors at the beginning of the application and maintain a pool of those through the applcation. Anyone helping to point to the right direction?

Comment: Writing to the filesystem is slow, don't expect it to be fast or consistent. Maintain single background thread to schedule writes in a fifo queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to go very low level. 
Have you considered using the `open()` `write()` and `close()` System calls.  The c-library fopen calls do some nice things for you such as buffering, but the system calls are likely to be faster.  You will have to profile, but I think you will see lower latency.

```
int fd = open("myfilepath",O_WRONLY|O_CREAT);
write(fd,myData, myDataSize);
close(fd);
```

You will find more info here. 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_system_calls/open.htm